# How to check if number is divisible in c#?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, double, division

I need to know how to do this procedure.

```
calculation1: 1/4 = 0,25
calculation2: 1/8 = 0,125
calculation3: 47/183 = 0,25683060109289617486338797814207......
calculation4: 58/889 = 0,06524184476940382452193475815523......
calculation5: 1/5 = 0,2
```

The results of calculations 1, 2 and 5 will give a short result, no periods or and endless string of digits. The results of calculations 3 and 4 are very long and complicated.

How can I check which calculation is an "easy one" and gives a "short" result.

I tried this and it gave a wrong result for sure...
like you can see, the results of the calculations have the datatype `double` in my application.

```
static bool IsInt(double x)
    {
        try
        {
            int y = Int32.Parse(x.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
```

I hope it is clear what I'm asking.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Define precisely your criteria for a number being 'easy' and a number being 'not easy'.  Your code will follow in a straightforward fashion.  The problem you have is not coding, but expressing precisely your requirement.

Comment: Are you asking about whether the result is a rational v. irrational number?  Or just is it short number (they all include decimals, so I'm not sure what you mean by no period)

Comment: @JeffHornby: All of his examples are rational, although he is forgetting about the limited resolution of `double`.

Comment: @JeffHornby I believe "no period" means that there is no infinitely repeating component in the fractional portion of the result. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function

Comment: Since all floating point values can't express infinite sequences, by definition every single float/double is rational and has a fixed number of [maximal] decimal digits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If after reducing the fraction as much as possible, the denominator can be expressed as a power of 2 multiplied by  a power of 5, then the decimal representation terminates. Otherwise it repeats indefinitely.

You could test if your division is "good" as follows:

```
public bool IsGoodDivision(int a, int b)
{
    while (b % 2 == 0) { b /= 2; }
    while (b % 5 == 0) { b /= 5; }
    return a % b == 0;
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/sPGAa)

Note that I am passing the numerator and denominator separately to the method. If you do the division first, then pass the result to your method, you lose precision due to floating point [representation error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

Also for production code you should check that `b != 0` because it is not allowed to divide by 0. Without the check the above code would go into an infinite loop.

Comment: +1 for the cleverness of this.  But, isn't it more practical to consider the technical implications of this question?  In other words, will this ratio overflow the data type?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, there is everytime something new to learn!

Comment: Nice, clean solution. You might add a counter for 2s and 5s in order to make sure that the solution does not have too many digits after the comma. But that would be only a guess from the original sample, not the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on your definition of "good result" or "easy one".  But I think what you want is the [Modulus Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).