# Incorect value for Float when using Json.toJson

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.4

I don't know if this is a bug in Play! or if there is another cause, but here is what is happening.

I have an object (`MyObject`) that has a member variable of type Float.

```
public class MyObject {
    private Float data;
}
```

When using `Json.toJson()` (from `play.libs.Json`) to send the response containing a `MyObject` item, the values get scrambled.

**As an example:**

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.setData(3.2f);
```

JSON string:

```
{
    "data": 3.200000047683716
}
```

If I change the data type to `Double`, everything works fine.

I suspect it may be because of float precision vs double precision and how `JSON.toJson()` handles `Float` objects, however, in debug, `myObj.data` is `3.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that 3.2 cannot be accurately represented by a `Float`. It actually can't be by a `Double` either, but the error is small enough that it gets thrown away.

Handy references:

- [Determine if a number can be precisely represented in float/double format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634461/determine-if-a-number-can-be-precisely-represented-in-float-double-format)
- [Decimal to floating point converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)